# SpreadSheetGear Right Click Menu Edit in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, winforms, ms-office, spreadsheetgear

Can I: Edit the right click menu of selected cells of Sheet in SpreatSheetGear to add an option like Merge, and then handle the event of selection of that menu item click?
Thanks in Advance for sharing some idea.

Comment: Please clarify which WorkbookView control you are using.  WinForms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: Dear Tim Andersen
It is WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to just be able add a new [ToolStripItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem(v=vs.110).aspx) to `WorkbookView.ContextMenuStrip` (the [ContextMenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.contextmenustrip(v=vs.110).aspx) property is inherited from the [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Control(v=vs.110).aspx) class):

```
' Create and add new item to WorkbookView's context menu
Dim newItem As ToolStripItem = workbookView.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Merge Cells")

' Add event handler
AddHandler newItem.Click, AddressOf MenuItemMergeCells_Click

...

Private Sub MenuItemMergeCells_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim item As ToolStripItem = CType(sender, ToolStripItem)
    If item.Text = "Merge Cells" Then
        workbookView.GetLock()
        Try
            ' Merging is only valid for multi-cell ranges
            If workbookView.RangeSelection.CellCount >= 2 Then
                workbookView.RangeSelection.Merge()
            End If
        Finally
            workbookView.ReleaseLock()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```